# Calling Jenkins Jason REST API from local html file in Firefox without changing the server

Tags: json, rest, firefox, jenkins, cross-domain

I try to GET data in JSON format from the local jenkins REST API.
I wrote a little html site with javascript to retrieve the data.

Sadly my browser is to paranoid to let this happen. And I have no controll over the browser config. (Our admin is quite anal about people playing with the settings).

This is the script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>

  <script>
  function UserAction() {

    console.log("Call Jenkins");

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://the.local.jenkins:1234/api/json?callback=foo";
    // script.type = "application/json";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }

  function foo(result) {

    console.log("callback!");

    var json = JSON.parse(result);

    console.log(json.mode);
  };
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <button type="submit" onclick="UserAction()">Search</button>
</body>

</html>
```

With this I get a syntax error when the "script" is parsed. Good thing is, the JSON data is there. Bad thing is, it is not usable.
When I comment in the line to declare the type as JSON than the error goes away and nothing happens.

Thing is, I don't want to change the jenkins installation (install some CORS plugin). Is there no way to load DATA from a remote domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you can convince your admin to change settings then this cannot be done through the browser as essentially you are performing a XSS attack.

You will have to do this on the server side of your web page using PHP or similar

```
<?php    $url = 'http://the.local.jenkins:1234/api/json'; $htm = file_get_contents($url); echo $htm;?>
```

note: the above code will just dump the whole Jenkins page, but I don't know PHP well enough to do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: We had a different solution: We installed a CORS Plugin that sets the Origin header. But yes, it is not possible to do it otherwise.